# Check if a string is palindrome

Tags: c++

I need to create a program that allows a user to input a string and my program will check to see if that string they entered is a palindrome (word that can be read the same backwards as it can forwards).

Comment: I would first start by clicking on the little "search" bar in the upper right, typing in "palindrome" and browsing through the dozens of possible answers across various languages..

Comment: @MikeChristensen That's a question tagged C, the kinds of things one would gripe about when debating answers would be different in C++...

Comment: If you need to check if a vector of integers is a palindrome or not: [LINK](https://pastebin.com/ZT5k55rf).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just compare the string with itself reversed:

```
string input;

cout << "Please enter a string: ";
cin >> input;

if (input == string(input.rbegin(), input.rend())) {
    cout << input << " is a palindrome";
}
```

This constructor of `string` takes a beginning and ending iterator and creates the string from the characters between those two iterators. Since `rbegin()` is the end of the string and incrementing it goes backwards through the string, the string we create will have the characters of `input` added to it in reverse, reversing the string.

Then you just compare it to `input` and if they are equal, it is a palindrome.

This does not take into account capitalisation or spaces, so you'll have to improve on it yourself.

Comment: I would vote your answer up, except the obvious gripe: it's homework, provide an approach/algorithm, not the code. What has the op learned from this exercise, laziness pays. :(

Comment: It doesn't work when string has the odd number of characters.

Comment: @ItiShree, I think you're mistaken.  If not, then please provide a counter-example.

Answer (score 80):

Note that reversing the whole string (either with the `rbegin()`/`rend()` range constructor or with `std::reverse`) and comparing it with the input would perform unnecessary work.

It's sufficient to compare the first half of the string with the latter half, in reverse:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    if( equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size()/2, s.rbegin()) )
        std::cout << "is a palindrome.\n";
    else
        std::cout << "is NOT a palindrome.\n";
}
```

demo: http://ideone.com/mq8qK

Answer (score 12):

```
bool IsPalindrome(const char* psz)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j;

    if ((psz == NULL) || (psz[0] == '\0'))
    {
        return false;
    }

    j = strlen(psz) - 1;
    while (i < j)
    {
        if (psz[i] != psz[j])
        {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return true;

}
```

// STL string version:

```
bool IsPalindrome(const string& str)
{
    if (str.empty())
        return false;

    int i = 0;                // first characters
    int j = str.length() - 1; // last character

    while (i < j)
    {
        if (str[i] != str[j])
        {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: sorry, the question is tagged C++ _and_ there is no justification to produce obfuscated code like this in this case (_ever_?). See [Cubbi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8362657/85371) for immediate proof

Comment: You really consider the code above as obfuscated?  Cubbi's solution is just STL kung-fu.  Nothing wrong with that.  But the code above is the classic solution to the problem - just not using STL.  To make you happy, I'll demonstrate a reasonable STL variation of the same solution.

Comment: admittedly it could be a lot worse. If you do the C++ (not necessarily STL) variant, let me remove my -1

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the "C++" variant that isn't STL.  Almost all C code is valid C++ code.  When someone speaks of a "string" in C/C++, I think "pointer to character". The "string class" is merely an encapsulation of a char pointer with extra overhead and some nifty features.  I've spent more years than I'll admit striving to make all lines of code I write readable, understandable, and maintainable. So you can see why I would get spazzed about my code being called "obfuscated".

Comment: have removed -1, I'd personally say that returning `false` for an empty string is a bug (one which would never have occurred when using std::equals, I might add). I'd also wager that common idiom would write the while loop as `for(int i=)` but - I guess that is down to habits

Comment: The code you wrote is C++, not STL. STL implies the use of STL features, such as iterators and algorithms. You use none of those. The C++-ness (in general) is in the fact that strings are first-class objects with managed lifetime and allocations. Also, strings contain null characters without problem. My point: _even if you dislike STL, the benefit of using C++ style is significant already; there should be no reason to use `char*` and `strlen` (because they are more error-prone and less flexible)_

Comment: @sehe Just curious. How much does the flexibility of *string* costs in terms of memory footprint and performance?

Comment: @RomanB - my point exactly.  I don't actually know.  But I do know this.  STL code is inherently harder to debug.  And if you don't pay attention, you will likely have less performant code if you abuse STL primitives, classes, and helper funcs.

Comment: @sehe - I'm not sure I buy the "string is a first class object" comment. It's just another STL class from my perspective.  Perhaps that has changed in C++11. Or perhaps I'm confusing STL with the the C++ runtime.  Either way, the compiler doesn't treat "string" instances differnet from any other class instances.  Can you site a reference that spells out the string library as native to C++ and not STL? If you are correct, I will have learned something new.

Comment: @RomanB: Just **[look at test.s](http://pastebin.com/FrDteYXD)** after `g++ -O2 -s -S -fno-exceptions` [`test.cpp`](http://pastebin.com/99PaAvTz). Better yet, just profile the darn thing

Comment: @selbie: **(a)** Re: debugging - there is simply less to debug. That helps **(b)** Re. 'native' or 'first-class': perhaps _[first-class wasn't clear to you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_object#Definition)_ - my point is that first class citizens avoid a whole universe of bugs, without sacrificing performance; also, [there is no such thing as 'the STL'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about). Also, yes `strings` are very much 'native' to the C++ standard: [§ 21.4 Class template basic_string](http://tinyurl.com/c-11-final).

Answer (score 1):

```
// The below C++ function checks for a palindrome and 
// returns true if it is a palindrome and returns false otherwise

bool checkPalindrome ( string s )
{
    // This calculates the length of the string

    int n = s.length();

    // the for loop iterates until the first half of the string
    // and checks first element with the last element,
    // second element with second last element and so on.
    // if those two characters are not same, hence we return false because
    // this string is not a palindrome 

    for ( int i = 0; i <= n/2; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( s[i] != s[n-1-i] )
            return false;
    }
    
    // if the above for loop executes completely , 
    // this implies that the string is palindrome, 
    // hence we return true and exit

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool isPalindrome(const std::string& str){

    if(str.empty()) return true;

    std::string::const_iterator itFirst = str.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator itLast = str.end() - 1;

    while(itFirst < itLast) {
        if (*itFirst != *itLast)
            return false;
    
        ++itFirst;
        --itLast;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(){

    while(1){
        std::string input;
        std::cout << "Eneter a string ...\n";
        std::cin >> input;

        if(isPalindrome(input)){
            std::cout << input <<  " is palindrome.\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << input << " is not palindrome.\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the string starting at each end and meet in the middle. Return false if there is a discrepancy.

```
#include <iostream>

bool palidromeCheck(std::string str) {
    for (int i = 0, j = str.length()-1; i <= j; i++, j--)
        if (str[i] != str[j])
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << palidromeCheck("mike");
    std::cout << palidromeCheck("racecar");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're able to manage reading a string from input or program arguments and writing a result to output, what you need is a predicate function that determines whether the string is palindromic.  The obvious approach is just to check whether it's equal to its own reflection:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

template<typename Char, typename Traits>
constexpr bool is_palindrome(std::basic_string_view<Char,Traits> const s) noexcept
{
    return std::ranges::equal(s, s | std::views::reverse);
}
```

However, this misses the simple optimisation that we only need to test the first half against the reflection of the second half (or vice versa):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

template<typename Char, typename Traits>
constexpr bool is_palindrome(std::basic_string_view<Char,Traits> const s) noexcept
{
    // Round down half size - any middle char will always match itself
    auto const r = s | std::views::reverse | std::views::take(s.size() / 2);
    return std::ranges::starts_with(s, r);
}
```

Since it's a template, it won't match strings or literals, so provide a couple of adaptors for things that convert to string-views:

```
// adaptors for specific types
constexpr bool is_palindrome(auto const& s) noexcept
{
    return is_palindrome(std::basic_string_view{s});
}
template <typename Char, std::size_t N>
constexpr bool is_palindrome(Char const (&s)[N]) noexcept
{
    return is_palindrome(std::basic_string_view{s, N-1});
}
```

And a selection of simple tests:

```
#include <string>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

using namespace std::literals;

TEST(is_palindrome, yes)
{
    EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome(""));
    EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome(L""s));
    EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome(L""sv));
    EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome("a"sv));
    EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome("aa"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome("aba"sv));
    EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome(L"abcba"sv));
    EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome("ab\0ba"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome("ab\0ba"sv));
    EXPECT_TRUE(is_palindrome(L"ab\0ba"));
}

TEST(is_palindrome, no)
{
    EXPECT_FALSE(is_palindrome("ab"));
    EXPECT_FALSE(is_palindrome(L"ab"sv));
    EXPECT_FALSE(is_palindrome("abc"));
    EXPECT_FALSE(is_palindrome("abca"));
    EXPECT_FALSE(is_palindrome("aab"));
    EXPECT_FALSE(is_palindrome("aa\0"));
    EXPECT_FALSE(is_palindrome(u8"abcab"sv));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bool IsPalindrome(string inputString)
{
   int left =0;
   int right = inputString.size()-1;
   while(left <= right){
       if(inputString[left++] != inputString[right--]){
           return false;
       }
   }
   
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This solution has already been covered in several other answers. I'm not seeing anything new here. In fact, the function will not behave correctly if the string is empty. Also, it's inefficient, as you only need to compare half the string to check for a palindrome.

Answer (score -3):

Reverse the string and check if original string and reverse are same or not