# Closest Palindrome Number

Tags: c++, algorithm, palindrome

I came across one of the common interview question which was to find the closest palindrome number. Say if the input is 127 then output will be 131 and if it is 125 then it should give 121 as output.

I can come up with the logic but my logic fails on certain cases like 91, 911. In these inputs it give 99 , 919 but the correct output is 88 and 909.

Algorithm steps are:

- Convert the number into string.
- copy first half to second half in reverse order
- convert to number and measure the abs. difference with original number diff1
- add 1 to half string and now copy first half to second half in reverse order
- convert to number and measure the abs. difference with original number diff2
- if diff1 is less than diff2 return first number else return second number

Comment: Sometimes there's a tie: the closest palindromes to 1000 are 1001 and 999. I think it can be established that there is always one closest palindrome that has the same number of digits. However, as you noted, the closest palindrome may share no digits in common with the number.

Comment: Folding the string as you describe gives one of the closest palindromes, either upper or lower depending. How do you get the other one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is actually an interesting problem. Obviously what you want to do to make this more than just a brute force is to use the most significant digits and put them in the least significant digit locations to form a palindrome. (I'm going to refer to the difference between the palindrome and the original as the "distance")

From that I'm going to say that we can ignore the least significant half of the numbers because it really doesn't matter (it matters when determining the distance, but that's all).

I'm going to take an abstract number:  `ABCDEF`. Where A,B,C,D,E,F are all random digits. Again as I said D,E,F are not needed for determining the palindrome as what we want is to mirror the first half of the digits onto the second half. Obviously we don't want to do it the other way around or we'd be modifying more significant digits resulting in a greater distance from the original.

So a palindrome would be `ABCCBA`, however as you've already stated this doesn't always you the shortest distance. However the "solution" is still of the form `XYZZYX` so if we think about minimizing the "significance" of the digits we're modifying that would mean we'd want to modify C (or the middle most digit).

Lets take a step back and look at why: `ABCCBA`

- At first it might be tempting to modify `A` because it's in the least significant position: the far right. However in order to modify the least significant we need to modify the most significant. So `A` is out.
- The same can be said for `B`, so `C` ends up being our digit of choice.

Okay so now that we've worked out that we want to modify `C` to get our potentially closer number we need to think about bounds. `ABCDEF` is our original number, and if `ABCCBA` isn't the closest palindrome, then what could be? Based on our little detour above we can find it by modifying `C`. So there are two cases, `ABCDEF` is greater than `ABCCBA` or that is less than `ABCCBA`.

If `ABCDEF` is greater than `ABCCBA` then lets add 1 to `C`. We'll say `T = C+1` so now we have a number `ABTTBA`. So we'll test to make sure that `ABCDEF - ABCCBA > ABCDEF - ABTTBA`
and if so we know that `ABTTBA` is the nearest palindrome. As any more modifications to C would just take us more and more distant.

Alternately if `ABCDEF` is less than `ABCCBA` then we'll subtract 1 from `C`. Let's say `V = C-1`. So we have `ABVVBA`, which just like above we'll test: `ABCDEF - ABCCBA > ABCDEF - ABVVBA` and you'll have the same solution.

The trick is that `ABCDEF` is always between `ABTTBA` and `ABVVBA` and the only other palindrome between those numbers is `ABCCBA`. So you only have 3 options for a solution. and if you compare `ABCDEF` to `ABCCBA` you only need to check 2.

I don't think it will be hard for you to adapt this to numbers of any size. and in the case of an odd number of digits you'd simply have `ABCBA`, `ABVBA` and `ABTBA` and so on...

So just like your examples: lets take 911.

1. Ignore the last 1 we only take the first half (round up). so 91X.
2. Replace X with 9. we have 919. this is out mid point.
3. We know our original 911 is less than 919 so subtract 1 from our middle number so we get our second (lower bound) 909.
4. Compare `911 - 919` and `911 - 909`
5. return the one with the smallest difference.

<strike>So this gives us a constant time algorithm :)</strike>
As pointed out in the comments this is not constant time in the worst case (oops), but is certainly better than a brute force approach.

This appears to be what you have, but I thought I'd elaborate to hopefully shed light on the issue as it seems to be a small programming error on your part otherwise.

Comment: Very nice way of doing it! +1. How did you get to this approach?

Comment: @HappyYellowFace: I sat and thought about it :)  Algorithms was one of my favorite subjects in my college studies

Comment: Very well thought, man. I'll try to implement it as soon as I get some free time.

Comment: There are two problems with the above solution: - 
1. Let's take an example 901. In this case, the correct answer is 898 but your algorithm will return 9 (-1) 9 which doesn't make any sense. To solve this you'd have to create a ripple kind of effect on the neighbors of the middle number.
2. This isn't a constant time algorithm. Its time complexity is O(d) where d is the number of digits in your number.

Comment: There will be some cases as well where you'd have to increment the middle number. For eg. in case of 129 (abc).. The nearest palindrome is 131. So the catch is to see if c - a> 5 we will increment and if a -c > 5 we will decrement and if both the cases we will leave the string as it is.

Comment: I guess I didn't explicitly state to make sure to turn -1 into a 9 and decrement the two outer numbers, but it's kind of implied. But I do see what you mean, worst case it's O(n)... I'll correct that in the answer, either way it's more efficient than the brute force approach. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I don't think I have a mistake in the answer pertaining to your second comment. In my example I say subtract, but in the general example I say look based on the number you make from the original. For instance, in your case of 129, you'd use the base number 121 which is less than 129, so you'd add 1 to the middle number and get 131. check which is closer. You don't subtract in that case because you'd just get farther from the original than the testing palindrome. From the answer: `If ABCDEF is greater than ABCCBA then lets add 1 to C.`

Comment: You know, if you avoid conversion to string, things are a lot easier and more efficient. See for example ["*The Next Palindromic number*" on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197816/the-next-palindromic-number) for how that improves things.

Comment: That link gives code to check if a number is a palindrome, but generating a palindrome using math does get quite tricky. While it might end up more efficient I'd argue that anything which does a conversion to strings would be much more readable and not sacrifice much in the way of efficiency... there are ways to handle this converting back and forth between strings and ints to keep things simple. Either way, this question is more about the algorithm than the implementation. Cool to see reading on the same topic though

Answer (score 4):

This is an implementation of Naveen's and Don's algorithm. It uses Happy Yellow Face's algorithm as a test oracle.

I would be happy to see people tweak it to remove redundant steps or special cases.

gcc 4.7.3: g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x nearest-palindrome.cpp

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// I do not have std::to_string.
template <class T>
std::string to_string(const T& v) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << v;
  return ss.str(); }

// Nor do I have std::stoi. :(
int stoi(const std::string& s) {
  std::stringstream ss(s);
  int v;
  ss >> v;
  return v; }

bool isPalindrome(int n) {
  const auto s = to_string(n);
  return s == std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend()); }

int specNearestPalindrome(int n) {
  assert(0 <= n);

  int less = n, more = n;
  while (true) {
    if (isPalindrome(less)) { return less; }
    if (isPalindrome(more)) { return more; }
    --less; ++more; } }

std::string reflect(std::string& str, int n) {
  std::string s(str);
  s.resize(s.size() + n);
  std::reverse_copy(std::begin(str),
      std::next(std::begin(str), n),
      std::next(std::begin(s), str.size()));
  return s; }

bool isPow10(int n) {
  return n < 10 ? n == 1 : (n % 10 == 0) && isPow10(n / 10); }

int nearestPalindrome(int n) {
  assert(0 <= n);
  if (n != 1 && isPow10(n)) { return n - 1; }  // special case

  auto nstr = to_string(n);
  // first half, rounding up
  auto f1 = nstr.substr(0, (nstr.size() + 1) / 2);
  auto p1 = stoi(reflect(f1, nstr.size() / 2));

  const auto twiddle = p1 <= n ? 1 : -1;
  auto f2 = to_string((stoi(f1) + twiddle));
  auto p2 = stoi(reflect(f2, nstr.size() / 2));

  if (p2 < p1) { std::swap(p1, p2); }
  return n - p1 <= p2 - n ? p1 : p2; }

int main() {
  std::vector<int> tests = { 0, 1, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 71, 74, 79, 99, 100, 999, 1000, 9900, 9999, 999000 };

  for (const auto& t : tests) {
    std::cout <<
      (nearestPalindrome(t) == specNearestPalindrome(t) ? "." : "X");
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0; }
```

Comment: isPalindrome could be improved. It is not necessary to copy the string in reverse order or to compare the full string.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a generic algorithm that would work<sup>1</sup>, although using brute-force:

```
int findNearestPalindrome(int n) {
    int less = n;
    int more = n;
    while(true) {
        if (isPalindrome(less)) return less;
        if (isPalindrome(more)) return more;
        --less;
        ++more;
   }
}
```

Within`isPalindrome()` function, all you need to do is convert the number to a string, and then [compare the string with itself reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8362607/1670308).

<sup>1</sup> <sub>However, this wouldn't check for tie cases, like Ted Hopp commented. You'd have to make a few changes to make it tie-recognizable.</sub>

Comment: I agree, this is a fine specification. I think the next question is, can the nearest palindrome be calculated, or found more efficiently?

Comment: See my answer for something more efficient. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>

// for convience
using namespace std; 
using ULL = unsigned long long int;

// calculate the number of digits
auto Len = [](auto num) -> ULL {
return floor(log10(num)) + 1; };

// extract left half of number
auto Halfn = [](auto num, auto olen) {
for (unsigned i = 0; i < olen / 2; num /= 10, ++i);
 return num; 
};

int main() {   
ULL num;   cin >> num;
// some basic checking   
if (num < 10)   {
cerr << "Error, enter a number >= 10";
return 0;   
}

if (numeric_limits<ULL>::max() <  num) {
cerr << "Error, number too large\n";
return 0;   
}
cout << ([](auto num) {   
auto olen = Len(num);   
auto lhalf = Halfn(num, olen);   

function<ULL(ULL)> palin = [olen]  (auto lhalf) { 
auto half = to_string(lhalf);
// this is the mirror string that needs to be  
// appended to left half to form the final 
// palindrome 
auto tmp = half.substr(0, olen / 2);

// take care of a corner case which 
// happens when the number of digits in 
// the left half of number decrease, while
// trying to find a lower palindrome 
// e.g.  num = 100000
// left half = 100  , the value passed to the  
// function palin, is 99. if all digits  are 9 
// then we need to adjust the   count of 9, 
// otherwise if i simply replicate it, i'll get 
// 9999 but one more 9 is required for the   
// correct output.

if (olen / 2 > tmp.size() &&
all_of(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(),
[](auto c) { return '9' == c; }))  {
tmp += '9';  
}

// append, convert and return   
half = half + string(tmp.crbegin(),                              
                   tmp.crend());
return stoull(half);  
};

auto bpalin = palin(lhalf);   
auto hpalin = palin(lhalf + 1);   
auto lpalin = palin(lhalf - 1);

stringstream ss;
ss << "base palindrome = " << bpalin <<'\n'; 
ss << "higher palindrome = "<<hpalin <<'\n';
ss << "lower palindrome = " << lpalin  <<'\n';

// calculating absolute difference for 
// finding the nearest palindrome

auto diffb = labs(bpalin - num);   
auto diffh = labs(hpalin - num); 
auto diffl = labs(lpalin - num);

auto nearest = (diffb < diffh) ? 
(diffb < diffl) ? bpalin : lpalin : 
(diffh < diffl) ? hpalin : lpalin;

ss << "nearest palindrome = "
     << nearest << endl;
    return move(ss.str());
 }(num)); 
} // end main
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    public String nearestPalindromic(String n) {
         int order = (int) Math.pow(10, n.length()/2);
    Long ans = Long.valueOf(new String(n));
    Long noChange = mirror(ans);
    Long larger = mirror((ans/order)*order + order+1);
    Long smaller = mirror((ans/order)*order - 1 );
    if ( noChange > ans) {
        larger = (long) Math.min(noChange, larger);
    } else if ( noChange < ans) {
        smaller = (long) Math.max(noChange, smaller); 
    }       
    return String.valueOf( ans - smaller <= larger - ans ? smaller :larger) ;
}
Long mirror(Long ans) {
    char[] a = String.valueOf(ans).toCharArray();
    int i = 0;
    int j = a.length-1;
    while (i < j) {
        a[j--] = a[i++];
    }
    return Long.valueOf(new String(a));
} 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Solution:

```js
const findNearestPalindrome = n => {
  if (!n) return 0;
  let lowestPalindorm = lowestPalindromeHelper(n);
  let largestPalindrome = largestPalindromeHelper(n);

  let closestPalindrome = 0;

  closestPalindrome =
    Math.floor(n - lowestPalindorm) > Math.floor(largestPalindrome - n)
      ? largestPalindrome
      : lowestPalindorm;

  console.log(closestPalindrome);
};

//lowestPalindrome check
const lowestPalindromeHelper = num => {
  for (let i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (isPalindrome(i.toString())) {
      return i;
    }
  }
};

//largest Palindrome Check
const largestPalindromeHelper = num => {
  for (let i = num + 1; i <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; i++) {
    if (isPalindrome(i.toString())) {
      return i;
    }
  }
};

const isPalindrome = n => {
  return (
    n ===
    n
      .split('')
      .reverse()
      .join('')
  );
};

findNearestPalindrome(1234);
```