# Identifying characters of a number

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, type-conversion, numbers

To analyze every character of a given number, like 2002, to be able to separate them I need to convert it to a string. But, as soon as I do that, how to manage this string?(its name and size). Just like when I need to say if the given number is a palindrome for example, after I convert the number to a string, how to manage this string?

Comment: _"how to manage this string?"_ Using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`to_string()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/), like this for example (printing every digit of the number, after converting the number to string, printing every character of the string that is):

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout
#include <string> // std::string, std::to_string

int main ()
{
  std::string str = std::to_string(2002);
  for(auto c: str)
    std::cout << c << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 2 0 0 2

---

PS: For the palindrome example you mention, please read [Check if a string is palindrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362572/check-if-a-string-is-palindrome).